# Running command line app on asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, console-application

I'm trying to get asp.net to run a console application on the server.  I can get it to run with the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = 
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath, "");
Process processChild = Process.Start(info); 
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

What I need is for the console app window to appear.  Currently it just runs as a process in the background.

Any ideas?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Where do you want to see the console window? On the server? Keep it in mind that you are doing it using ASP.NET and everything is happening in the server and you can see nothing from the client machine.

Comment: Yes that is what I want (server).  The console app will run for a long time and I'd like to be able to login to the server and check its status.  I realise I could use the output in asp but i'd rather just have the console window open instead.

Comment: Have put CreateNoWindow = false before Process.Start but still doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice, you are starting the process before setting `CreateNoWindow` to false. Do it like this instead:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = 
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath, "");
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process processChild = Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: ..oh yeah.  Just tried the other way around, still doesn't open.  Can see it in the task manager though.

Comment: If you are seeing it in the task manager, what is the user name shown against the process? Probably you are logging in as a different user and not getting that session.

Comment: Ah I see.  The user is the IIS Application.  Thank you for your help.  [This guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/12/02/startprocessasuser.aspx) shows how to specify a user, if anyone else needs to know.

Comment: @Simon: Right. The issue needed a bit of observation.